# regex to match string that only has one uppercase letter

Tags: php, regex

I am curling an page and getting the output

however what is happening is that the html encoding is being removed so new lines are being skipped,

so it looks like this

```
This is Bob. He lives in an boatBut he only has one oar to row with.
```

in order to detect new lines I figure it was easier to just check for strings that only have One upper case letter and spaces inbetween, so far I have this

```
(\s\w+\s\w+.\s\D+[a-z][A-Z])
```

However this does not seem to work

as it only matches this

```
 is Bob. He lives in an boatB
```

see here http://regex101.com/r/gH0lW1

how to match all strings that have spaces and match all strings up to one Uppercase letter

Answer (score 0):

**Update: this will split on the condition without losing any characters**

```
<?php

$string = "This is Bob. He lives in an boatBut he only has one oar to row with.He also does stuff, it is cool.";
$array = preg_split('/(?<=[a-z.])(?=[A-Z])/', $string);
print_r($array);

?>
```

---

Use a positive lookbehind to ensure you capture a capital after a lowercase:

```
(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]
```

http://regex101.com/r/cB7bD8

You could use php's [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) if you want, to explode the result on this regex.

Comment: this only matches the B i need it to match This is Bob. He lives in an boat

Comment: @user3117904 `(?<=[a-z])[A-Z].*`

Comment: this matches But he only has one oar to row with. i need it to match the first bit, cheers

Comment: @user3117904 yeah, that's where explode comes in. Hang on, I'll get you some sample code.

Comment: @user3117904 ok, updated answer. There's an example there, that will split it into an array for you. You can then re-stitch it together however you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?(?:\w+(?=[A-Z]))|\1)
```

This regex has a recursive part that will match more than 1 sentence in a whole text. So you can check the [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/aI9iI0) and see the matched groups.

***But,***

*If you wanna include a newline on each sentence begins after a period (.) **as well**, then I modify above regex to this:*

```
(.*?(?:(?:\w+|\. *)(?=[A-Z]))|\1)
```

*and now you can compare results with the first regex [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/gQ0pY0)*